# Resetting the value of array in contiguous integers using foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Resetting the value of array in contiguous integers(1,2,3,4...)  using foreach in PHP

I have a array like(1,3,3,4,5,6)

how can i reset the values like (1,2,3,4,5,6) using foreach loop

Comment: You want an array as the same as it currently is? This question is extremely vague & hard to understand. To avoid the current imminent closure, can you expand?

Comment: `$newArray = range(min($originalArray), max($originalArray));`

Comment: @MarkBaker that will give very unpredictable results for for example an input of `[5,6,7,8,9]`...

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes - unpredictable? I'm pretty sure I can predict what result it will give without even needing to execute it

Comment: @MarkBaker you'd return `[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]` - hardly what he describes as intended result. Also, he wants to use `foreach` - otherwise the valid answer would indeed be `range(1, count($originalArray))`.

Comment: You've obviously misread the document page for [range()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)... the second argument is not a count, it's an end value. My answer will give `[5,6,7,8,9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($array as &$item)
  $item = $i++;
```

[See here in action](https://eval.in/190431).

Comment: Is this not essentially `count(array)`?

Comment: @DarylGill `$i` will be that at the end, but it's just a helper variable. This code turns `[5,4,3,9,2]` into `[1,2,3,4,5]`, using `foreach`. As far as I understand, that's the question. Perhaps you're missing the amperstand before `&$item`?

Comment: I completely understand you are using $i as a reference. It's a little hard to decide what OP is trying for at this moment in time imho

Comment: @DarylGill The question seems pretty clear to me, this answer is spot-on.